# How to create table from csv with fields having tabs in values?

Tags: csv, amazon-athena

I have to create table from csv in Athena and using SerDe.
One of the csv fields include values as follows:

""Value"

still the same value

but in multiple lines

and it has to be

in one column"",

I am creating external table and using:

CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `tmp_test` (

`id` varchar(4000),

`value' string))

ROW FORMAT DELIMITED FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','

ESCAPED BY '"'

STORED AS INPUTFORMAT

'org.apache.hadoop.mapred.TextInputFormat'

OUTPUTFORMAT
'org.apache.hadoop.hive.ql.io.HiveIgnoreKeyTextOutputFormat'

and select id, value from tmp_test gets following:

| id | value |
| --- | --- |
| "0001" | "Value" |
| still the same value |  |
| but in multiple lines |  |
| and it has to be |  |
| in one column" |  |

Would you please help me with serde properties to get proper result?